# Having a little issue with Flurl (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: flurl

Hello Stackoverflow Users,

I just want to use an API of someone, but he did'nt put a release on github so you have to compile the api for yourself.

The API im trying to use, is using Flurl, i imported everything but now i have some errors and i can't compile the api.

(Note: im asking here for help because im not that advanced enough to know how i can fix this)

The error is saying:
**Cannot implicitly convert type 'Flurl.Http.IFlurlClient' to 'Flurl.Http.FlurlClient' An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)**

[A Screenshot of the Error in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nw94S.png)

(The API Iam trying to use is https://github.com/Tustin/psn-csharp)

Answer (score 0):

The `IFlurlClient` interface was introduced in [Flurl.Http 1.1](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/releases/tag/Flurl.Http.1.1.0), but the source code you're working with [uses 1.0.1](https://github.com/Tustin/psn-csharp/blob/master/PSN/packages.config). If you downgrade to Flurl.Http 1.0.1 you should be fine. It might be easiest to just start over, i.e. re-download the API source and don't upgrade the NuGet packages.

Comment: That Worked! Thank you.